# What do these constraints mean?

Tags: arrays, constraints

Can anyone help me understand this coding problem assignment?

I have an array of numbers, where each number appears twice except for one, and I need to identify which is the number that only appears once.

E.g.

const num_list = [8, 6, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 7, 7, 6]
Answer: 5

The thing I'm confused about though is the constraints given for the problem are:

2 <= num_list[i] <= 100000

3 <= i <= 10,000

In particular the second constraint given - What does 'i' refer to here? Is it just stating the minimum number of elements that will be in the array (there are multiple test cases with different arrays as input)? Or does it mean that if I iterate over the array I can only start iterating from index 3 of the array onwards?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just ask your teacher?

Comment: @j08691 Because that's probably some online coding challenge.

Comment: `i` is an arbitrary index in the array. The first constraint means that all values in the array are between 2 and 100000. The second constraint means, that the array is between 3 and 10000 elements long